# Setting dynamic button titles in iOS8 local notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I have followed the examples here and elsewhere for setting up 1 or 2 button local notifications and have that working just fine. The examples are just fine if you need canned buttons like Accept/Delete/etc, but I need need to set the button titles for what is happening in the app at the time. This is for a game and needs a generic engine. I need to be able to set the button titles to match the needs at the time. I have two categories so I can do one button or two button notification. It seems like the actions and categories need to be setup when you register for the notification. The title on the UIMutableUserNotificationCategory is shown as "read only". I know this can be done. For example the game "Spy Watch" can be played 90% of the time from the notifications.

Is there anyway set the titles when scheduling the notification? I have passed dictionaries with the data I need to process the response.

This is the AppDelegate side

```
NSString * const NotificationCategoryIdent1  = @"1BUTTON";
NSString * const NotificationCategoryIdent2  = @"2BUTTON";
NSString * const NotificationActionOneIdent = @"ACTION_ONE";
NSString * const NotificationActionTwoIdent = @"ACTION_TWO";

- (void)registerForNotification {

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action1;
action1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
[action1 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
[action1 setTitle:@"Button 1"];
[action1 setIdentifier:NotificationActionOneIdent];
[action1 setDestructive:NO];
[action1 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

UIMutableUserNotificationAction *action2;
action2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
[action2 setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
[action2 setTitle:@"Button 2"];
[action2 setIdentifier:NotificationActionTwoIdent];
[action2 setDestructive:NO];
[action2 setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory2;
actionCategory2 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
[actionCategory2 setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent2];
[actionCategory2 setActions:@[action1, action2]
                forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory1;
actionCategory1 = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
[actionCategory1 setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryIdent1];
[actionCategory1 setActions:@[action1]
                forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:actionCategory1, actionCategory2, nil];
UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                             categories:categories];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
}
```

Here is how I set up the notification in my view controller

```
UILocalNotification* localNotification2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification2.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30];
localNotification2.alertBody = @"Alert Body2";
localNotification2.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification2.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
localNotification2.category = @"2BUTTON";
//localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification2];
```

Comment: Im a little confused by your wording. Can you explain your problem in 1 sentence?

Comment: I would like to be able to change the titles of the defined actions during runtime. .... That was the one sentence version, Examples: one time I call actionCategory2 I might want action1's title to be "Go Right" and action2 to be "Go Left" were the next time it might be "Give the item" and "Keep Item". I don't want to define in advance every possible one or two button action in the game.

Comment: what are defined actions?

Comment: This is for local notifications. When the notification is called you supply a category (UIMutableUserNotificationCategory). A category is made up of UIMutableUserNotificationAction's. The UIMutableUserNotificationAction have a "title" that is used as the button labels. They are the defined actions I am talking about. I could have 100's of categories that each have different actions assigned to them, but it would be better to allow my program to supply the button labels during runtime.

Comment: Why are you registering it in the AppDelegate then? Why not do it at runtime when you have the name and set it to whatever you want?

Comment: Good question.... Lets say you wait until you need it actually send the notification. How do you fire the notification the second time with new info? It also seems like you need to ask permission (register) early for them to have approved it enough before firing the notification for it to me allowed. I have seen it fail if fired while its waiting for the user to respond to the request the first time. Also all examples I have seen have done the register in AppDelegate and show firing in view controllers (if not done in AppDelegate for a simple example)

Comment: You just create a new notification as you need it?

Comment: This is a iOS and WatchOS app. For WatchKit to see the category it needs to be registered in AppDelegate. Well at least in the Ray Wenderlich book it say it does.

Comment: No thats not how they work

Comment: Got any solution ?